# GCP storage issue

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage

Trying to wrap my head around what this error really means, but it's saying `Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to...` when I try to get fileData from a bucket file.

```
app.get('/api/videos', (req, res) => {
  const storageBucket = storageClient.bucket(config.video_bucket);
  storageBucket.getFiles(function(err, files) {
    if (!err) {
      let fileArray = [];

      files.forEach(function(file) {
        const videoAnnotationBucket = storageClient.bucket(config.video_json_bucket);
        const videoAnnotationFilename = (file.metadata.name).replace('/', '').replace('.', '') + '.json';
        const annotationFile = videoAnnotationBucket.file(videoAnnotationFilename);

        // GET ANNONATIONS FOR EACH FILE
        annotationFile.get(function(error, fileData) {
          if (error) {
            console.log('error getting file', error);
          }
          else {
            const remoteJsonUrl = fileData.metadata.mediaLink;
            // console.log(fileData.metadata);

            request({
              url: remoteJsonUrl,
              json: true
            },
            function(jsonReadErr, jsonResp, body) {
              console.log('logging body:');
              console.log(body);
```

The error is occuring on the callback, and I'm reading the error via `console.log(body)` which gives me the error message I stated above.

What's weird is it's saying I'm anonymous when I did `gcloud auth login` as well as I'm providing creds when I declare `storageBucket` as such:

```
const storageClient = storage({
  credentials: {
    "client_email": "clientEmail",
    "private_key": "privateKey",
  },
  projectId: "projectId"
});
```

So right off the bar, to avoid any "did you set this" questions, no I am not actually supplying those values I omitted the real values, and we use them elsewhere so I know they are correct.

My question is, what does `Anonymous caller` mean? And how can I fix it? How is it thinking I am anonymous when I did all the (seemingly) necessary things to use the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you need to explicitly authenticate within request. [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48502826/access-to-cloud-storage-from-client-url) looks related.

Let us know how explicitly authenticating worked out!

Comment: Did it a different way, but essentially, yes.